# Угар как синоним потери контроля

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Наверное, в заголовке не совсем правильно сформулировано. Но говорят, что кто-то был "в пьяном угаре", а также часто "угар" говорят о состоянии, когда человек, как говорится, бросается во все тяжкие. Вот пример из классики:
*И я склонился над стаканом,

Чтоб, не страдая ни о ком,

Себя сгубить

В угаре пьяном.

(С. Есенин)*

И все-таки, при чем тут ядовитый газ СО?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Угар - многозначное слово.

> Толковый словарь русского языка под редакцией Т. Ф. Ефремовой
>
> **УГАР**
> 1) Удушливый ядовитый газ, образующийся при неполном сгорании топлива; ~ный газ. 2) а) Болезненное состояние при отравлении таким газом. б) перен. разг. Состояние сильного опьянения. 3) перен. разг. Состояние крайнего возбуждения, самозабвения, экстаза. 2. м. 1) Убыль - в объеме, в весе - при плавке, горении, термической обработке. 2) Потеря сырья при переработке волокна, пряжи (в текстильной производстве).

Если можно отравиться газом, то и жидкостью (алкоголем) тоже можно...

> Ф. М. Достоевский. Записки из мертвого дома (1862)
> А между тем у всякого была своя повесть, смутная и тяжелая, как **угар от вчерашнего хмеля**.